# How Do I call A WCF Web Service from jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, wcf, web-services

How can i call a wcf service from jquery (i am using asp.net mvc). This is what i used to do with asmx webservices :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Services/MyService.asmx/DoSomething",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        //do the magic
    }
});
```

How do I do the same with a WCF service?

Comment: @Yassir: this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608006/where-am-i-going-wrong-in-calling-asmx-web-methods-from-jquery. You may not realize it, but you're not calling WCF, but the legacy ASMX services. That's why it says ".asmx".

Comment: @John Saunders : i know what the code i posted is what i usualy do to call asmx services and now i want help with wcf :) (this is not aduplicate :d )

Comment: @John Saunders : why did you change the title and the tags ? did you read the question first ?

Comment: @Yassir: Yes, I read it. You didn't _say_ anything. The entire question was the code, and I had to read closely to see that it's the code that you _used to_ use. Notice how it looks with my most recent edit.

Comment: @Yassir: have you tried my suggestion yet? Is this working for you?

Comment: @John Saunders : i tried this : http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/324917.aspx and it works fine ;) thx

Answer (score 1):

Yassir,

The precise details of how you call a specific WCF service will depend on the service. For instance, is it a SOAP service, or a REST service? JSON or Plain XML.

The good news is that if your WCF service is exactly the same as your ASMX service, then you can call it in exactly the same way.

The bad news is that, if your WCF service is different, then calling it will be different.

Comment: I already created the service and it is working all i need is call it with jquery

Comment: What happens when you try to call it?

Comment: i don't know how to call it because all the examples i found create a proxy to consume the webservice in (C# or VB)

Comment: Please just try calling it in the EXACT same way you did with the ASMX, then see what happens. I don't know why you expect it to be totally different. You say you created the service and it's working. How did you test it? Have you tested it returning JSON? What part of calling this service do you not understand?