# How to call WCF Web Service (.svc) using jQuery

Tags: web-services, jquery

Hi I am trying to call a WCF web service(.svc)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.somedoamin.com/Services/service.svc',
    dataType: "text/xml",
    contentType:'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        // Pass the soap action onto the proxy.
        xhr.setRequestHeader(
            "SOAPAction","http://www.anotherdomain.com/Services/Login"
        );
    },   
    data:soapMessage,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(res) {
            var myXML = res.responseText;
    console.log('Response ',myXML);  
    },
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown,exception) {
        console.log('An error occured ');
    }
});
```

I am getting error callback. "An error occured"

So, Should i need to add some parameters to WCF Service ?

Comment: How does the **webservice** look like? How does `soapMessage` look like?

Comment: What does jQuery "say" in the error handler (`textstatus`, `errorThrown`)?

Comment: Are you sure you are not violating the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this existing [How Do I call A WCF Web Service from jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083219/how-do-i-call-a-wcf-web-service-from-jquery?rq=1)

This is the solution they given 
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Apr/21/jQuery-AJAX-calls-to-a-WCF-REST-Service